# Describing the chromatic scale of a piece

Tags: chromatic

I am currently analysing Variation 12 of the Mozart Piece called "Ah, vous dirai-je, Maman". One of the questions I am doing says to "Describe the chromatic scale and whether it is ascending or descending". I'm just a bit confused about what this actually means. Is ascending or descending just referring to the contour of the piece?

Answer (score 1):

Before I looked at the sheet music, my answer was to describe how oftentimes **the accidentals of the chromatic scale tell you its role.** An ascending chromatic scale will use *raised* pitches (sharps with some naturals if there are flats in the key signature) while a descending chromatic scale will use *lowered* pitches (flats with some naturals if there are sharps in the key signature). This is just a practical matter to prevent too many accidentals, as shown in the image below; don't the first four measures look much cleaner than measures 5--8? It's the difference between using (in this case) 5 accidentals as opposed to 10.

[image]

But then I looked at the sheet music, because I couldn't remember exactly which variation was the twelfth one. Now I say: **Whoever asked you this question could have asked it much, much more clearly.** I'm even wondering if it's actually meant for Variation XII, as this question seems to apply to Variation X a bit better.

Comment: "...as this question seems to apply to Variation X a bit better." It would apply even better still to the second half of Var. VIII (the minor-key contrapuntal variation). There are chromatic *notes* in Vars X and XII but it doesn't make much sense to describe them as any type of *scale* IMO.

Comment: As a 'newbie', I would say the first example is in, the C Chromatic Scale. The Second example, is the same Scale, in the 'En-Harmonic Equivalent'.
C# is equal to, and the same as, D flat.